# Make Hangout ring rather than the phone ring for incoming calls

Tags: google-hangouts

I have a lousy mobile service with weak signals. When I use wifi, I want to use Google Hangout to receive incoming calls.

I have associated the phone's number with my Google Voice number.

- At first, I forwarded incoming calls to my GV to my phone (by checking the box before my associated phone number in GV settings), but then my phone's Phone app always hijack the incoming calls (I don't know if that is because I set up something on my phone), and I can't answer the calls using Hangout.
- Then I stopped forwarding incoming calls to my GV to my phone (by unchecking the box before my phone number in GV settings), but then Hangout doesn't ring for incoming calls.

My phone is Kyocera Hydro Icon with Android 4.4.2.